# Why does tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]' includes empty line?

Tags: tr

I'm working through [Unix For Poets](https://www.cs.upc.edu/~padro/Unixforpoets.pdf), and trying make a file containing all words/tokens in the [Bible](http://janelwashere.com/files/bible_daily.txt). However, when using tr, as suggested, this includes the empty string. See example below:

```
> tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]' < bible.txt > bible.words
> sed 5q bible.words

The
Project
Gutenberg
EBook
```

I have read through the man page for tr, without any luck. Any help with understanding why their included would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

*First example:*

Line from bible.txt:

> 1:1 Paul, a servant of Jesus Christ, called to be an apostle,

Command which reproduces the unexpected result:

```
> echo '1:1 Paul, a servant of Jesus Christ, called to be an apostle,' | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]'

Paul
a
servant
of
Jesus
Christ
called
to
be
an
apostle
```

Expected output:

```
Paul
a
servant
of
Jesus
Christ
called
to
be
an
apostle
```

*Second example:*

Line from bible.txt:

> The Project Gutenberg Ebook of The King James Bible

command with same unexpected result:

```
echo 'The Project Gutenberg EBook of The King James Bible  ' | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]'

The
Project
Gutenberg
EBook
of
The
King
James
Bible
```

Expected output:

```
The
Project
Gutenberg
EBook
of
The
King
James
Bible
```

Note its the prefix empty line I don't understand.

Comment: reproduce the problem for 2 lines, show bible.txt for those lines and show our expected and current output

Comment: Updated the question with expected and actual output.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your second example. `echo 'The Project Gutenberg EBook of The King James Bible  ' | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]'` is not giving me empty first like. However in your first example it is expected as there is a space after `1:1` before next word.

Comment: can reproduce with simple `1:1the project` as input string... as initial `1:1` will be replaced with newline... won't be a problem if there are alphabets at start of string... `'is1:1the project'`... can use `grep -oi '[a-z]*'` as alternate if your `grep` implementation supports this

Comment: @Sundeep So '1:1' becomes truncated into '' which is split by a newline due to the space. Is this only the case if the complement characters prefix first word (with a space)? Fx. echo '1:1 Paul 1:1 a a' | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]' does not produce an empty line between 'Paul' and 'a'. The first example is reproduced when doing: sed 1q < bible.txt |  tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '[\12*]', or copying directly from the file. However, it doesn't reproduce when I copy from browser.

Comment: @OlaR for `'1:1 Paul 1:1 a a'` case, all the newlines between `Paul` and `a` are **squeezed** to single newline... that is what `-s` option is for... remove it and see it in action for yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the `tr` options at work here to know what's going on.

1. `-c` => complement the first character set. Means, any chars not found in the first char set are to be selected. In your case, `'A-Za-z'` will imply any nonalphabetics like a space, a number, a newline, a control char would be chosen.
2. `-s` => multiple consecutive chosen chars are to be `squashed` in as a one.
3. The second set is the chars that are to be mapped into. `\12` is the octal ascii for a newline.

That means all alphabets(both upper & lower case) are to be left untouched whilst runs of non-alphabetics shall be turned into a single newline:

```
     ----     --        --------     -     -       -----      ----
$#%! This     is        StarWars     R2    D2      robot     @work.
|---|    |---|  |------|        |---| |---| |-----|     |----|    ||
 \n        \n      \n             \n    \n     \n         \n      \n
```

All the alphabets are untouched while a run of multiple nonalphabets are turned into newlines.

---

```
output:

This
is
StarWars
R
D
robot
work
```

Comment: Was about to write u didn't address the question, but edit (with prefix chars) fixes it.